# Centos: OK to install JDK over the JRE?

Tags: linux, java

We have the JRE running fine on Centos 7.

Our app provider wants us to run some utils from jdk (e.g. jstack).

Can we just run the jdk rpm over the top of the jre, and all will be well?

(using Centos7, 1511, from August 2016, and the latest and greatest jre from the same time frame)

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply speaking JDK is a full version of the JRE, or, in other words, JDK comprises the JRE and superseeds it. Usually they do install in different directories and the location of the binaries is handled with the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Furthermore, it is common  to host multiple JDK/JRE installations on the same host, of different versions.

So, basically, it's ok. Many things can go wrong, but not from a simple fact that you have multiple JDK/JRE on the same host.

Comment: Thanks. I get all that. Where is the write up on how to have multiple java engines, and to control which is in use at any given time?

Comment: It's installed in `/usr/java` in Centos/RHEL, and whis is used by default is controlled by the symlinks `latest` and `default`.